# Why dont work select with quotes?

Tags: php, mysql

Good day.

I have row in database:

[image: database]

When i make first select:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` Like '%Коляска \"Balmoral\" Silver Cross%'
```

i get null(num rows = 0)...
But if i make second select:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `name` Like '%Balmoral%'
```

i get num rows = 1.

Why not work first select and how make right select?

**Slashes in database and in select becose i use mysql_real_escape_string when i insert new row and use select**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT *  FROM `titles` WHERE `title` LIKE '%Коляска \\\\"Balmoral\\\\%" Silver Cross'
```

**Explanation: the \ must be escaped with \ for SQL, but for PHP we need extra \ for escaping also.**

Or Simply:

```
SELECT *  FROM `titles` WHERE `title` = 'Коляска \\"Balmoral\\" Silver Cross'
```

However, I don't know why!!!

Comment: `Like` not good idea in this operation. 

Need use fulltext.

Example

`SELECT *, MATCH (name) AGAINST
    ('Коляска \"Balmoral\" Silver Cross') AS score
    FROM products WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST
    ('Коляска \"Balmoral\" Silver Cross');`

Answer (score 2):

The backslash is an escape character. If you want to look for it you need to escape it. (In other words, you need to escape the escape character.):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` Like '%Коляска \\"Balmoral\\" Silver Cross%
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `name` Like '%Коляска \\"Balmoral\\" Silver Cross%'` i get null rows...

Answer (score 0):

Like not good idea in this operation. Need use fulltext.

Example

```
SELECT *, MATCH (name) AGAINST
    ('Коляска \"Balmoral\" Silver Cross') AS score
    FROM products WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST
    ('Коляска \"Balmoral\" Silver Cross');
```